# How can I make the native controls on a React Native expo-av Video visible?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, expo-av

I need to know how to assign a function to an expo-av Video component's onPress event, or how to make a useRef reference trigger an onPress event on an expo-av Video component.

I have a lot of requirements for a React Native video component and I am trying to work out how to best achieve them all. The main issue is the user needs to be able to double-tap the video and have an animation fire. We have a Pressable component that renders over the video that handles a double tap. The animation works fine. But the problem is there's also a requirement that the video uses native controls, and the Pressable blocks those controls.

I have two strategies but I haven't been able to achieve either. Plan A, someone on StackOverflow tells me that expo-av Video components have some kind of onPress function not listed in their docs, and all I have to do is trigger the double tap animation using that function. So far I've tried onPress, onTouchEnd, onTouchStart, and onClick, and all are undefined and not listed in the docs. No dice.

Plan B, I can create a Pressable component that renders over the Video component that is short enough not to block the native controls, but tall enough to catch all other taps. Then, when a user double-taps the Pressable, the animation fires and everything's good. This is what I initially submitted as a solution, but our QA folks said they need the native controls to show on the first press. Normally the native controls are not visible and the expo-av Video shows them on any press, but the Pressable blocks those presses, and I cannot find anything in the docs that allows you to referentially trigger the expo-av press event. I have a useRef() working and have tried videoRef.current.press, videoRef.current.click, and videoRef.current.setStatusAsync({ progressUpdateIntervalMillis: 0 }). No dice. I just need the control buttons to show up like they normally do on a tap, nothing else.

So in summary, does anyone A: Know how to assign a function to the expo-av Video component's onPress event? or B: Know how to make a useRef reference trigger an onPress event on an expo-av Video component? or C: Some other solution I haven't thought of?

Here are some code snippets if it helps:

The Video instantiation:

```
<Video
          ref={(video) => videoRef.current = video}
          style={[styles.postMedia, { width: videoDimensions.width, height: videoDimensions.height }]}
          source={{ uri: videoUrl }}
          rate={1.0}
          volume={1.0}
          isMuted={isMuted}
          resizeMode={Video.RESIZE_MODE_CONTAIN}
          shouldPlay={shouldPlay || screenIsFocussed && (keyInView === _id)}
          isLooping
          useNativeControls
          onError={(e) => setVideoUrl(`${getS3BaseUrl(video.s3Bucket)}/${video.url}`)} 
          onReadyForDisplay={(response) => {
            const { width, height } = response.naturalSize;
            if (width >= height) return setVideoDimensions({ width: screenWidth, height: screenWidth * height / width });
            if (height > width) return setVideoDimensions({ height: screenWidth, width: screenWidth * width / height });
          }}
        />
```

The handleDoubleTap function:

```
  let lastTap = null;
  const handleDoubleTap = () => {
    const now = Date.now();
    const DOUBLE_PRESS_DELAY = 300;
    if (lastTap && (now - lastTap) < DOUBLE_PRESS_DELAY) {
      toggleLike();
    } else {
      if (videoRef) videoRef.current.setStatusAsync({ progressUpdateIntervalMillis: 0 }); // <-- insert something that actually works here
      lastTap = now;
    }
  };
```

The Pressable component instantiation:

```
{(video || image) && (
        <Pressable
          onPress={handleDoubleTap}
          style={video ? {
            ...styles.videoLikePostFromFeedPressable,
            height: IS_IOS ? DEVICE_WIDTH * 0.75 : DEVICE_WIDTH * 0.66,
          } : {
            ...styles.likePostFromFeedPressable,
            height: DEVICE_WIDTH,
          }}
        >
          {renderOverlay()} {/* <-- This is just the animation render, works fine */}
        </Pressable>
      )}
```